# How to validate a form based on a condition in angular 6?

Tags: angular, forms, angular6

I have one drop down. Based on the selection of the drop down I need to display some columns along with the existing columns which is common for every selection.

```
My html:

<mat-form-field class="col-xl-6 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" placeholder="EntityName" (selectionChange)="changeEntity($event.value)" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let type of types" [value]="type.viewValue">
          {{type.viewValue}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>

 <div *ngIf="selectedValue === 'One'" class="row formGroup">
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" class="col-xl-6 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <input matInput placeholder=" OneID" type="text" id="oneid" formControlName="oneid">
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>

  <div class="row formGroup">
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" class="col-xl-6 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <input matInput placeholder="Name" type="text" id="commonname" formControlName="commonname">

      </div>
    </mat-form-field>
<div class="formGroup" *ngIf="selectedValue === 'Two'"
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" class="col-xl-6 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <input matInput  type="text" id="username" formControlName="twoname">
    </mat-form-field>
 </div>
```

My Ts File:

```
  myForm = this.fb.group( {
    oneid: ['', Validators.required],
     commonname: ['', Validators.required],
     oneid: ['', Validators.required],
     twoname:['',Validators.required],

   })

 get f() {

    return this.myForm.controls;
 }
 if (this.myForm.invalid) {
  console.log("invalid");
  return;
}
```

So My doubt is how will do validation? If I keep formcontrol name for separate fields, My form is returning invalid. How can I do validations for this nested inputs & get the value of every input fields without having separate formcontrol names? Please guide me.

Comment: Unable to understand what you are asking at first glance!

Comment: Can you produce this in stackblitz

Comment: You can check validation of your form's properties separately using **get()**, for example **this.myForm.get("oneid").invalid**

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-data-jfzl5g?file=app%2Fselect-form-example.html

Comment: @Vignesh I have commented the stackblitz link. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to avoid formcontrol names. What you need is dynamic validation.

Inside your `onSubmit()` method change validation rules dynamically.
You can write code like this:

```
if(some-condition) {
this.entityForm.get('eid').clearValidators();
this.entityForm.get('principalEntity').clearValidators();
this.entityForm.get('tel').clearValidators();
this.entityForm.get('rilid').clearValidators();

this.entityForm.get('eid').updateValueAndValidity();
this.entityForm.get('principalEntity').updateValueAndValidity();
this.entityForm.get('tel').updateValueAndValidity();
this.entityForm.get('rilid').updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

Note that you need to clear validation rules on specific controls based on some condition by calling `clearValidators()`.
Also, you need to call `updateValueAndValidity()` to let them be re-evaluated.